# Google Maps: Where to upload the 3d models and the kml objects so everyone could see the 3D Objects?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, kml

I'm trying to add a 3d object to Google Earth.
I'm making the model in Google SketchUp and the KML file but I don't know where to upload the file so that everyone who use google maps could see the model.

Could you share with me this information? :)

Answer (score 1):

Placemarks and overlays ( [Basic training](http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/showflat.php?Cat=0&Board=wisdom&Number=16256&PHPSESSID=&fpart=1#Post16256) ) <<<< Click here

OR

[Creating a New Placemark](http://earth.google.com/userguide/v4/ug_placemarks.html#new) <<<< Click here

(1) Add one using the menu at the top. Give it a name and usually it's also a good idea to add some description in the description box

(2) Right-click on your placemark in the Goolge Earth view or on the item in your 'Places' list on the left.

(3) Choose 'Save As' from the menu that appears

(4) Give the saved file a name and make a note of where it's being saved.( I Use my desk top)

(5) Then,to attach your placemark, after you type your post, make sure the "I want to preview my post and/or attach a file" is checked.

(6) On the next view, use the Browse button to find that file you saved earlier and click "open". Click "Continue" or "Submit" and you are finished!

**And Remember There's a whole world to see, but there are some things you can do to see it better.If a place is well known or famous for some reason, there is always a good chance that another member has posted it before. There are two main ways to help you to see what others have placemarked and posted. 
First, it is always a good idea to check the Google Earth Community Forum layer, which is where previous placemarks are identified (it is updated every few months, so a placemark you post today will be in there soon). To activate the layer, just check the box.**

[image]

The second is to use the [**SEARCH**](http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/search.php?Cat=0) page. This method will detect posts too new to to have been included in the layers.

To add new information about a feature which has already been placemarked, make a reply to the placemark and post already in place. You can access the original post by left-clicking on it and then left-clicking on the link.

If you discover that you have mistakenly added a duplicate placemark, It is good GEC etiquette to remove it by editing your post and choosing the "DELETE" option.